# Were Peter Davison, Colin Baker, and Sylvestor McCoy in Day of the Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who, behind-the-scenes, the-day-of-the-doctor

In [*The Five(ish) Doctors Reboot*](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p01m3kfy) ('Day of the Fish Doctor'), Peter Davison, Colin Baker, and Sylvestor McCoy

> appear in *Day of the Doctor* as the covered statues (actually Zygons)

as the 11th (or 12th, depending on how you count) Doctor walks past.

Were these three actors present on set, as depicted, when this was filmed?

Comment: Awesome! I hadn't heard this one before.

Answer (score 9):

According to an "inside story" article on [Digital Spy](http://www.digitalspy.com/british-tv/s7/doctor-who/tubetalk/a533941/doctor-who-the-inside-story-on-the-fiveish-doctors-reboot.html), Steven Moffat (lead writer and executive producer) says:

> There are things that you don't do to three highly-distinguished actors and one of them is you don't really drape them under a sheet for several hours!

But this is countered by Peter Davison's quote:

> Of course it was us under the sheets! How could it not be? Don't ask such questions!

So there you go.  Two people who should know the answer, making public statements that contradict each other.  You'll just have to choose which authoritative source to believe.

Comment: Haha. Excellent. I'm sure it wasn't them, but it sure is fun to think it was.

Comment: Except that those quotes aren't equivalent in their conviction. Peter Davison's is a *"Yes, it happened"*, Steven Moffat's is a tongue-in-cheek *"How dare you think I'd do that, I'd never do that because it's a very naughty thing to do"*... which basically also translates to a *"Yes, it happened"*.

Comment: Yes, Hashim, you are correct.  Your skills at detecting tongue-in-cheek responses are clearly not non-existent.

Answer (score 6):

It is strongly implied by "The Five(ish) Doctors Reboot" that Sylvester McCoy, Colin Baker and Peter Davison are underneath the sheets in the scene where Kate Stewart, Clara and The Doctor (11th) enter the under-gallery; however that companion show is basically a mockumentary. I would like to think that they did appear (albeit as Zygons-in-waiting rather than Doctors past), but I'd like to see actual confirmation from the actors or the BBC that this was the case, and not just a sort of clever cinematic trick.

On a complete side note: it is unclear what role Tom Baker was playing at the end of "The Day of The Doctor"; he was referred to as the "Curator" and not the Fourth Doctor, but then again, Elizabeth I had appointed The Doctor (the Tenth Doctor, anyway) as her curator of the under-gallery. I think it is intentionally ambiguous; another interpretation is that it is a future regeneration that uses the same "template" as the Fourth Doctor.

Comment: Re. your 2nd paragraph; that is a separate question: [How did Tom Baker fit in the Day of the Doctor?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/45381/204)

Comment: Clearly that is the implication; what the question is asking for is such clarification. A response from someone that was there or a link to such.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Davison, Colin Baker and Sylvestor McCoy did indeed appear in *The Day of the Doctor*, but not necessarily in person.

The answer by **onigame** presents the conflicting evidence on whether they were under the sheets in the scene mentioned in the question (Steven Moffat says they were not, Peter Davison says they were). Considering that *The Five(ish) Doctors Reboot* is a spoof about the actors who previously played the doctor trying and failing to get in on the anniversary episode, I'm inclined to think that it is Davison who is joking. But everyone is free to decide for themselves.

The scene where they definitely appear is, of course, the one where the 13 TARDISs surround Gallifrey during the Daleks' final attack. We see a brief image of each Doctor as he contacts Gallifrey's War Council. The images and audio were not recorded for the anniversary special, but were taken from those Doctors' original episodes.

I haven't verified this, but [The TARDIS Wikia](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Doctor_(TV_story)) states that the footage came from

- Fifth Doctor: *Frontios* with audio from *The Five Doctors*
- Sixth Doctor: *Attack of the Cybermen*
- Seventh Doctor: *Battlefield* and *Doctor Who* (the 1996 movie)